# how to select and move using a Base Point in blender

Tags: transforms

Suppose I have a group of vertices, and I want to grab them by a special vertex, and move them to wherever I want (sort of like the way "Move" function works in AutoCAD). I googled this and came up with this webpage:
[https://developer.blender.org/T45734#:~:text=Grab%20with%20basepoint&text=press%20G%20(grab),on%20vertex%20snap%20is%20activated](https://developer.blender.org/T45734#:%7E:text=Grab%20with%20basepoint&text=press%20G%20(grab),on%20vertex%20snap%20is%20activated))

Please find below the screenshot of the page. I was wondering, is this reliable data? Because I hit G and then B, and nothing happens. Perhaps I should enable something in the  Preferences menu? Also, any other solutions for the original problem is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: That's just a request, not a feature that is already in Blender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Set snap to,pay attention to Active
  [image]
- Choose the point which you want(white) and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and choose other vertices.
  [image]
- Hold<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,press<kbd>G</kbd> and move to the point which you want snap to.
  [image]